# how to fix 'Error: Cannot find module 'nconf'?

Tags: electron

Reference: https://medium.com/developers-writing/building-a-desktop-application-with-electron-204203eeb658#.w1gam0oa6

I have downloaded the code throught ZIP file and after I launch the application with `c:\NodeJS\4.0-x64\node_modules\electron-prebuilt\dist\electron.exe c:\sound-machine-electron-guide-master`

I have seen this:

[image].

I have installed the electron prebuild on `c:\NodeJS\4.0-x64\node_modules\electron-prebuilt\dist\electron.exe`

What may be the reason that cause the issue?